# React handle change function works without parameter event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created three components:

1. `<MyInputComponent>` extends the material ui component
2. `<Input>` handles the onChange of `<MyInputComponent>` by accepting as props `onInputTyping` and passing it to the `onChange` of `<MyInputComponent>`
3. `<App>` renders `<Input>` and passes to `onInputTyping` of `<Input>` a `handleTypying` function

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bas-u0rj4

Inside **Input** I have:

```
const Input: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { onInputTyping } = props;

  return (
    <MyInputComponent
      onChange={(event) => onInputTyping && onInputTyping(event)}
    />
  );
};
```

Inside **App** I have:

```
export default function App() {
  const handleTyping = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input onInputTyping={(event) => handleTyping(event)} />
      <br />
      <Input onInputTyping={() => handleTyping(event)} /> <-- This still console.log the event, but why?
      <br />
      <Input onInputTyping={handleTyping} /> <-- This still console.log the event, but why?
    </div>
  );
```

**Question:**
I am not understanding why the last two `<Input>` inside `App` are able to console.log the event that the user types.

I am passing the `event` only in the first `Input`, and this `event` is then passed to `handleTyping`. Example: `<Input onInputTyping={(event) => handleTyping(event)} />`

**but**

in the second and third `<Input>` I am not passing any `event` to `handleTyping`. So,
how is it possible that `handleTyping` is able to console.log(event) even if I am not passing any `event` to it?

Comment: If the onInputTyping attribute is a callable, it is called with the event as parameter. This explains first and last behaviour. In the middle, maybe the event object is in the closure of the callback caller and then it works too. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JonasWilms The second gives me a type error but it stills console.log . I agree that is the weirdest of the three

Comment: @MetallimaX Nothing to achieve in particular. I was curious about the behaviour

Comment: As I said first and last are "equivalent" the only difference is that in the first case you pass through an anonymous function that call the `handleTyping` function with an event argument and in the last case it works directly without the anonymous function. But it is the same process, an external caller is calling the attribute callback with the event parameter.

Comment: Also, it works this way: onInputTyping={() => handleTyping(this.event)}, the event property is part of the function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause there is a global [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) variable. If you omit the parameter of the function, `event` will refer to that (in your second example). By coincidence the `React.ChangeEvent` that is received via the parameter and the global variable holding an `HTMLEvent` have the same properties, that's why it "works".

Your third example is not much different than your first which I think can best be illustrated by removing all the React around it and just showing the functions:

```
 function realHandler(event) {
   //...
 }

 function callback(handler) {
    handler(event); // this is doing exactly the same thing as the following line
    realHandler(event); 
 }

 callback(realHandler);
```